# Issue with submitting the form when the button in search bar is clicked in react

Tags: reactjs

I am having issue with when a user inputs a value in the search bar and click the button it either throws an error in the console (`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0`) and the value passed to the handleSubmit is undefined. However, I am able to pass the value when I hit the enter button as `keyPress function` please let me know what I am doing wrong and thank you in advance!

**SearchBar.js**

```
    const Navbar = ({ searchBarText, setSearchBarText }) => {
      
    
      function handleSubmit(e){
    
          console.log('submitted Value', e.target.value);
          setSearchBarText(e.target.value)
          e.preventDefault();
      }
      function keyPress(e){
        if(e.keyCode === 13 || e.key === 'Enter' ){
           console.log('value', e.target.value);
           setSearchBarText(e.target.value)
           // put the login here
           e.preventDefault();
        }
      }
    
    
      return (
            <>
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light  ">
                    
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="search-container" >
                 <span className="search-icon-btn">
                   <button className="search-icon-btn" type="submit"  onClick={handleSubmit} >
                    <i className="fa fa-search" value={searchBarText}></i>
                   </button>
               </span>
               <div className="search-input">
               <input 
                  type="text" 
                  className="search-bar" 
                  placeholder="Search...."
                  onKeyDown={keyPress}
            
               />
           </div>
         </div>

        </form> 
    
            </nav>  
            </>
          
        );
    
        
      }
      
    export default Navbar;
```

[image]

When I click the highlighted button the data in console shows undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event passed to `handleSubmit` is the click event on the button, so `e.target.value` is the value of the button, which is presumably undefined.

The quickest fix is to give the input an Id and select its value to pass to `setSearchBarText`:

```
const searchInput = document.getElementById("searchInput");
setSearchBarText(searchInput.value);
```

A "better" fix is to use state. Bind a handler to the input's `onChange` or `onInput` that updates a state value. Then you can bind a single submit handler to both the button's `onClick` and the input's `onKeyDown` that retrieves the state value and passes it to `setSearchBarText()`

Comment: Hello @ChiefMcFrank I tried adding the getElementById to my `handleSubmit` and also added the `id` to my `input field` but in console the output was `<input id="searchInput" type="search" class="search-bar" placeholder="Search ticker symbol..."> ` instead of a string.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add `.value` to searchInput. Updated my answer - `setSearchBarText(searchInput.value);`

Comment: thank you so much it worked! ChiefMcFrank